# Complete removal and reinstall of autogenStudio to resolve incorrect api key error

Tags: devops, openai-api, autogen

How do you completely purge and re-install autogenstudio from from [scratch](https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/issues/1415) trying to resolve error [401: Incorrect API Key](https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/issues/1415). How do you delete all old autogenStudio files, reinstall all dependencies. Before resorting to a complete purge I resolved the 401 error, temporarily successful, following Github thread steps [401: Incorrect API Key](https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/issues/1415) by [deleting](https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/issues/1415#issuecomment-1944427419) my models, agents in AutogenStudio UI, but this error recurred.

Do you need any autogen installation or dependencies not included with `pip install autogenstudio`? Because after attempting to uninstall autogenStudio, and deleting files, and install from scratch using the [autogenstudio instructions](https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/blog/2023/12/01/AutoGenStudio/#running-the-application) when I get to  `pip install -e .`  I get `ERROR: file:///C:..//STUDIO does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py'`  Adding those files from github doesnt help either.

#### Some more detail:

1. Environment: Windows 10,  VsCode launched using anaconda.navigator so it's in a virtual conda environment
2. RE 401 error: I noticed that it was reporting an older api key that was different than `export open_api_key=sk.....A` instead it was providing error  `Report:Error occurred while processing message: Error code: 401 - {'error': {'message': 'Incorrect API key provided: sk-..............B. You can find your API key at [https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys).', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': 'invalid_api_key'}}` then took these troubleshooting steps unsuccessfully: tried to find the older key in my code, could not, then unsuccessfully: cleared browser cache, used different browser, tried something like 'pip cache purge' (though I cant remember exactly), pip uninstall autogenstudio, deleted files in `file:///C:..//STUDIO`  directory, though not other locations like `\AppData\Local\`